# Data from an api depend on another api

Tags: reactjs, api

Hi i wanna make an api call which depends another API. One API give me the ID from a random movie, and the second give me the details about that movie. All is separated in a file api.js and exported to a component. If i export the function i get a Promise how is fullfilled but not the movie details. How can i resolve this nested API? Here is the code if its help

```
 export async function getMovieDetail() {
 const data = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day? 
  api_key=${apiKey}`).then((res) => res.json());
 const movie = data.results[random].id;

 async function getMovieById() {
 const data = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie}? 
 api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US`).then((res) => res.json());
 return data;
 }
 const movieDetail = await getMovieById();
 return movieDetail;
 }
```

Comment: you don't need `.then()`  in the `await` statement

Comment: You mean in the second api call?

Comment: can you please share the code instead of an image, it will be easy to reply with code

Answer (score 0):

chain both requests like this

```
export async function getMovieDetail() {
        return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/day? 
         api_key=${apiKey}`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                const movie = data.results[random].id;
                return fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${movie}? 
                           api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US`)
                      
            }).then((res) => res.json());
}
```

Comment: If i export the function i can't use the data. Because you export a function and in the component i need the function to give me the details. But if i want to use the details i need to make an await

Comment: yes, If you are working with React, the most common pattern is to fetch the data inside useEffect and show a loading spinner or something till the data comes from the API

Comment: just want to point out that any `async` function returns a promise even if you are only retuning a number

Comment: I found the answer using useEffect

Comment: I think my answer fairly answer your question, if you think it's not then you have asked the wrong question